# How to generate unique student id (e.g 2014-444-168) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am creating an enrollment system that should generate an unique student id upon submitting a form. The unique id is not included in the form field. Rather it will be generated using the store method in the `StudentController` class. Please refer to my code below.

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function store(StudentRequest $request)
    {
        $student = Student::create($request->all());

        $student->id_no = "12345669";

        $student->save();

        return redirect('index');
    }
}
```

As shown above I want to create the student id. Can someone please suggest best practices of doing the above task

Comment: Maybe you could base it with actual timestamp (creation timestamp) and a unique property of your student

Comment: @Delphine Thanks. I was thinking about that.

Answer (score 0):

This will be unique:

```
$student->id_no = date("Y").'-'.$student->id;
```

And even this will be unique:

```
$student->id
```

Because it's auto incremented primary key and it can't be duplicated.

Comment: Thanks mate. I will consider that.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a string to the `$student->id` and generate similar but unique values. Like you find in college ids.